# Firebase Realtime Database not working on NextJS only after build - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I used Firebase Realtime Database with Next.js, for back-end.

And I wrote the below code. But It works only in local, not in production. The reason I comments some lines as follows is that I want to show that the error was not caused by my code. `onValue`, `get`, `set`, `update` were all the same. The same error was raised. And also I confirmed that effect function in `useEffect()` runs only once.

```
/* lib/firebase.ts */

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Realtime Database
export const database = getDatabase(app);
```

```
import { onValue, ref, update } from 'firebase/database';
import { database } from 'lib/firebase';
...

useEffect(() => {
  onValue(
    ref(database, `objects/${user.uid}`),
    (snapshots) => {
      console.log(snapshots);

      // const fetchedObjects: Common.Object[] = [];

      // snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      //   fetchedObjects.push({ key: snapshot.key, ...snapshot.val() } as Common.Object);
      // });

      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   setObjects(fetchedObjects);
      //   setIsObjectLoaded(true);
      // }, 500);
    }
  );
}, []);
```

As a result of `console.log()`, a snapshot object with no children was returned. But It should be a snapshot object with serveral child nodes according to database state. It is the case in local.

Only in production, the below error was raised. `_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js` was bundled by Next.js, so It was so complicated that I couldn't read it. But when I deduce from comments, maybe it can be `firebase/database` code.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:770)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:897)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:906)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:897)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:906)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:897)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:906)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:897)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:906)
    at i (_app-e9aaf40698fc4780.js:1486:897)
```

1486 line's code is here.

```
 */ let e3,e4,e6=new class extends eW{compare(e,t){let n=e.node.getPriority(),r=t.node.getPriority(),i=n.compareTo(r);return 0===i?q(e.name,t.name):i}isDefinedOn(e){return!e.getPriority().isEmpty()}indexedValueChanged(e,t){return!e.getPriority().equals(t.getPriority())}minPost(){return eq.MIN}maxPost(){return new eq(j,new e2("[PRIORITY-POST]",e4))}makePost(e,t){let n=e3(e);return new eq(t,new e2("[PRIORITY-POST]",n))}toString(){return".priority"}},e5=Math.log(2);class e8{constructor(e){var t;this.count=parseInt(Math.log(e+1)/e5,10),this.current_=this.count-1;let n=parseInt(Array(this.count+1).join("1"),2);this.bits_=e+1&n}nextBitIsOne(){let e=!(this.bits_&1<<this.current_);return this.current_--,e}}let e9=function(e,t,n,r){e.sort(t);let i=function(t,r){let s=r-t,o,a;if(0===s)return null;if(1===s)return o=e[t],a=n?n(o):o,new eG(a,o.node,eG.BLACK,null,null);{let l=parseInt(s/2,10)+t,u=i(t,l),c=i(l+1,r);return o=e[l],a=n?n(o):o,new eG(a,o.node,eG.BLACK,u,c)}},s=new e8(e.length),o=function(t){let r=null,s=null,o=e.length,a=function(t,r){let s=o-t;o-=t;let a=i(s+1,o),u=e[s],c=n?n(u):u;l(new eG(c,u.node,r,null,a))},l=function(e){r?(r.left=e,r=e):(s=e,r=e)};for(let u=0;u<t.count;++u){let c=t.nextBitIsOne(),h=Math.pow(2,t.count-(u+1));c?a(h,eG.BLACK):(a(h,eG.BLACK),a(h,eG.RED))}return s}(s);return new eY(r||t,o)},e7,te={};class tt{constructor(e,t){this.indexes_=e,this.indexSet_=t}static get Default(){return(0,f.hu)(te&&e6,"ChildrenNode.ts has not been loaded"),e7=e7||new tt({".priority":te},{".priority":e6})}get(e){let t=(0,f.DV)(this.indexes_,e);if(!t)throw Error("No index defined for "+e);return t instanceof eY?t:null}hasIndex(e){return(0,f.r3)(this.indexSet_,e.toString())}addIndex(e,t){(0,f.hu)(e!==e$,"KeyIndex always exists and isn't meant to be added to the IndexMap.");let n=[],r=!1,i=t.getIterator(eq.Wrap),s=i.getNext();for(;s;)r=r||e.isDefinedOn(s.node),n.push(s),s=i.getNext();let o;o=r?e9(n,e.getCompare()):te;let a=e.toString(),l=Object.assign({},this.indexSet_);l[a]=e;let u=Object.assign({},this.indexes_);return u[a]=o,new tt(u,l)}addToIndexes(e,t){let n=(0,f.UI)(this.indexes_,(n,r)=>{let i=(0,f.DV)(this.indexSet_,r);if((0,f.hu)(i,"Missing index implementation for "+r),n===te){if(!i.isDefinedOn(e.node))return te;{let s=[],o=t.getIterator(eq.Wrap),a=o.getNext();for(;a;)a.name!==e.name&&s.push(a),a=o.getNext();return s.push(e),e9(s,i.getCompare())}}{let l=t.get(e.name),u=n;return l&&(u=u.remove(new eq(e.name,l))),u.insert(e,e.node)}});return new tt(n,this.indexSet_)}removeFromIndexes(e,t){let n=(0,f.UI)(this.indexes_,n=>{if(n===te)return n;{let r=t.get(e.name);return r?n.remove(new eq(e.name,r)):n}});return new tt(n,this.indexSet_)}}/**
```

I can't interpret the code, and I can't figure out the cause, so I'm going crazy. Help me.

---

+) I also tested on the new Next.js project created by create-next-app.

```
npx create-next-app@latest --typescript
cd {project folder name}
npm install firebase
```

And the code I wrote is here.

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, onValue, ref } from "firebase/database";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      ...
    };
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getDatabase(app);

    // It works only in local
    onValue(ref(db, "???"), (snapshots) => console.log(snapshots));
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

As a result, like my project, the same error was raised. But It works well in local.

Comment: It's pretty hard to interpret a `DataSnapshot` as it mostly shows implementation details. What does it output when you `console.log(snapshots.val())`?

Comment: That output was `null`.

Comment: This looks unexpected `ref(db, "???")`. Do you really have a node called `???` in your database? Can you show a screenshot of that?

Comment: Yes. I really have that node(`???` just expresses an arbitrary path), so the data in that path are fetched well in local. If the path was wrong, the data won't be fetched in local, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this post.

I resolved this problem by downgrading Next.js version from 12.3.1 to 12.3.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).